# how to give one viewController add and edit functionality using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using storyboard and Xcode 5. I am new to ios.
How can i give a same view controller two functionality
User can add data and edit data as well.
I have bar button in my navigation bar.
DispalyDataController 1 : UITableView
AddEditController 2 : Textfields, label simple form data
Once AddEditController 2 is filled up then it must be displayed on tableview on DispalyDataController 1

I am using below code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

  AddEditController *controllerAddEdit;
 controllerAddEdit.arraypassed = self.dataArray;

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set identifier by selecting an segue and move to attribute inspector

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Edit"] ){

  AddEditController *controllerAddEdit = segue.destinationViewController;
  controllerAddEdit.editModeOn = YES;
  controllerAddEdit.arraypassed = self.dataArray;

     }

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Add"] ){

    AddEditController *controllerAddEdit = segue.destinationViewController;
    controllerAddEdit.editModeOn = NO;

   }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your view controller is nil, you need to pull it out of the segue... Try this...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    AddEditController *controllerAddEdit = (AddEditController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    controllerAddEdit.arraypassed = self.dataArray;
}
```